# Latex tabular text alignment

Tags: tables, align

I have made the following table in tex:

```
\documentclass{standalone} 

\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
%\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
%\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\bgroup
\def\arraystretch{1.5}%  1 is the default, change whatever you need

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular} {l>{\flushleft\arraybackslash}p{3.55cm}>{\flushleft\arraybackslash}p{12.5cm}}

\toprule

& Autor (Jahr) & Definition \\ 
\hline

\multirow{14}*{\rotatebox{90}{Systemrisikobeitrag}}
& LAWARE (1991) &
"Systemic risk refers to the possibility that financial difficulties at one bank, or possibly a small number of banks, may spill over to many more banks and perhaps the entire financial system. So long as problems can be isolated at a limited number of banks, but confidence maintained in the broader banking and financial system, there is little or no systemic risk.", S. 550. \\ 
& BANK FÜR INTERN. ZAHLUNGS- AUSGLEICH (1994) &
"The risk that the failure of a participant to meet its contractual obligations may in turn cause other participants to default, with the chain reaction leading to broader financial difficulties", S. 177. \\
& ROCHET/TIROLE (1996) &
"Systemic risk refers to the propagation of an agent's economic distress to other agents linked to that agent through financial transactions", S. 733.  \\
& HELLWIG (1998) & 
"[Systemrisiko soll] das Problem bezeichnen, daß (!) aufgrund von wechselseitigen Abhängigkeiten verschiedener Institutionen in einem Finanzsystem die Schwierigkeiten einer Institution die Funktionsfähigkeit des gesamten Systems infrage stellen können", S. 125. \\

\noalign{\bigskip}
\cline{2-3}

\multirow{10}*{\rotatebox{90}{Systemrisikoempfindlichkeit}}
& DAVIS (1995) & 
",Systemic risk‘ [is] used to describe a disturbance in financial markets which entails unanticipated changes in prices and quantities in credit or asset markets, which lead to a danger of failure of financial firms, and which in turn threatens to spread so as to disrupt the payments mechanism and capacity of the financial system to allocate capital", S. 117. \\
& BARTHOLOMEW/ WHALEN (1995) &
"Systemic risk refers to an event having effects on the entire banking, financial, or economic system rather than just one or a few institutions", S. 4. \\
& MISHKIN (1995) &
"Systemic risk is the likelihood of a sudden, usually unexpected, event that disrupts information in financial markets, making them unable to effectively channel funds to those parties with the most productive investment opportunities", S. 32. \\

\noalign{\bigskip}
\cline{2-3}

\multirow{12}*{\rotatebox{90}{Systemkorrelationsrisiko}}
& DAS/UPPAL (2004) & 
"The risk from infrequent events that are highly correlated across a large number of assets", S. 2810. \\
& ERGUNGOR/ THOMSON (2005) &
"In a systemic crisis, multiple banks fail simultaneously, and the collective failure impairs enough of the banking system’s capital so that large economic effects are likely to result and the government is required to intervene", S. 2. \\
& KRAHNEN (2006) &
"Das systemische Bankenrisiko ergibt sich aus dem gemeinsamen Ausfall mehrerer (juristisch) unabhängiger Finanzinstitute. Das so verstandene systemische Risiko eines Finanzmarktes gibt Auskunft über die Wahrscheinlichkeit, dass aufgrund negativer Entwicklungen mehrere Bankinstitute gleichzeitig in Schwierigkeiten geraten", S. 58. \\
& ACHARYA (2009) & 
"We define systemic risk as the joint failure risk arising from the correlation of returns on the asset side of bank balance sheets", S. 225. \\

\bottomrule

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This is the output of above code:

[image]

My problem is that the text in the third column is only flushed left by \flushleft. But I want it left aligned in grouped style (like when I only using p{12.5cm} for this column).
How can I get this done?

The main problem is that I want the second column flushed left like it is done now. The other reason why I'am using >{\flushleft\arraybackslash}p{12.5cm} for the third column is that this creates extra space between the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three additional possibilities using either `tabularx` or an `itemize` list:

[image] [image] [image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3.5cm}X@{}}

\toprule

& Autor (Jahr) & Definition \\ 
\midrule

\multirow{16}*{\rotatebox{90}{Systemrisikobeitrag}}
& LAWARE (1991) &
"Systemic risk refers to the possibility that financial difficulties at one bank, or possibly a small number of banks, may spill over to many more banks and perhaps the entire financial system. So long as problems can be isolated at a limited number of banks, but confidence maintained in the broader banking and financial system, there is little or no systemic risk.", S. 550. \\ 
\addlinespace
& BANK FÜR INTERN. ZAHLUNGS- AUSGLEICH (1994) &
"The risk that the failure of a participant to meet its contractual obligations may in turn cause other participants to default, with the chain reaction leading to broader financial difficulties", S. 177. \\
\addlinespace
& ROCHET/TIROLE (1996) &
"Systemic risk refers to the propagation of an agent's economic distress to other agents linked to that agent through financial transactions", S. 733.  \\
\addlinespace
& HELLWIG (1998) & 
"[Systemrisiko soll] das Problem bezeichnen, daß (!) aufgrund von wechselseitigen Abhängigkeiten verschiedener Institutionen in einem Finanzsystem die Schwierigkeiten einer Institution die Funktionsfähigkeit des gesamten Systems infrage stellen können", S. 125. \\

%\noalign{\bigskip}
\cmidrule{2-3}

\multirow{12}*{\rotatebox{90}{Systemrisikoempfindlichkeit}}
& DAVIS (1995) & 
",Systemic risk‘ [is] used to describe a disturbance in financial markets which entails unanticipated changes in prices and quantities in credit or asset markets, which lead to a danger of failure of financial firms, and which in turn threatens to spread so as to disrupt the payments mechanism and capacity of the financial system to allocate capital", S. 117. \\
\addlinespace
& BARTHOLOMEW/ WHALEN (1995) &
"Systemic risk refers to an event having effects on the entire banking, financial, or economic system rather than just one or a few institutions", S. 4. \\
\addlinespace
& MISHKIN (1995) &
"Systemic risk is the likelihood of a sudden, usually unexpected, event that disrupts information in financial markets, making them unable to effectively channel funds to those parties with the most productive investment opportunities", S. 32. \\

%\noalign{\bigskip}
\cmidrule{2-3}

\multirow{13}*{\rotatebox{90}{Systemkorrelationsrisiko}}
& DAS/UPPAL (2004) & 
"The risk from infrequent events that are highly correlated across a large number of assets", S. 2810. \\
\addlinespace
& ERGUNGOR/ THOMSON (2005) &
"In a systemic crisis, multiple banks fail simultaneously, and the collective failure impairs enough of the banking system’s capital so that large economic effects are likely to result and the government is required to intervene", S. 2. \\
\addlinespace
& KRAHNEN (2006) &
"Das systemische Bankenrisiko ergibt sich aus dem gemeinsamen Ausfall mehrerer (juristisch) unabhängiger Finanzinstitute. Das so verstandene systemische Risiko eines Finanzmarktes gibt Auskunft über die Wahrscheinlichkeit, dass aufgrund negativer Entwicklungen mehrere Bankinstitute gleichzeitig in Schwierigkeiten geraten", S. 58. \\
\addlinespace
& ACHARYA (2009) & 
"We define systemic risk as the joint failure risk arising from the correlation of returns on the asset side of bank balance sheets", S. 225. \\

\bottomrule

\end{tabularx}

\clearpage
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{\quad}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3.5cm}X}

\toprule

 Autor (Jahr) & Definition \\ 
 
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\itshape Systemrisikobeitrag}\\
\midrule

 LAWARE (1991) &
"Systemic risk refers to the possibility that financial difficulties at one bank, or possibly a small number of banks, may spill over to many more banks and perhaps the entire financial system. So long as problems can be isolated at a limited number of banks, but confidence maintained in the broader banking and financial system, there is little or no systemic risk.", S. 550. \\ 
\addlinespace
 BANK FÜR INTERN. ZAHLUNGS- AUSGLEICH (1994) &
"The risk that the failure of a participant to meet its contractual obligations may in turn cause other participants to default, with the chain reaction leading to broader financial difficulties", S. 177. \\
\addlinespace
 ROCHET/TIROLE (1996) &
"Systemic risk refers to the propagation of an agent's economic distress to other agents linked to that agent through financial transactions", S. 733.  \\
\addlinespace
 HELLWIG (1998) & 
"[Systemrisiko soll] das Problem bezeichnen, daß (!) aufgrund von wechselseitigen Abhängigkeiten verschiedener Institutionen in einem Finanzsystem die Schwierigkeiten einer Institution die Funktionsfähigkeit des gesamten Systems infrage stellen können", S. 125. \\

\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\itshape Systemrisikoempfindlichkeit} \\
\midrule

 DAVIS (1995) & 
",Systemic risk‘ [is] used to describe a disturbance in financial markets which entails unanticipated changes in prices and quantities in credit or asset markets, which lead to a danger of failure of financial firms, and which in turn threatens to spread so as to disrupt the payments mechanism and capacity of the financial system to allocate capital", S. 117. \\
\addlinespace
 BARTHOLOMEW/ WHALEN (1995) &
"Systemic risk refers to an event having effects on the entire banking, financial, or economic system rather than just one or a few institutions", S. 4. \\
\addlinespace
 MISHKIN (1995) &
"Systemic risk is the likelihood of a sudden, usually unexpected, event that disrupts information in financial markets, making them unable to effectively channel funds to those parties with the most productive investment opportunities", S. 32. \\


\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\itshape Systemkorrelationsrisiko} \\
\midrule

 DAS/UPPAL (2004) & 
"The risk from infrequent events that are highly correlated across a large number of assets", S. 2810. \\
\addlinespace
 ERGUNGOR/ THOMSON (2005) &
"In a systemic crisis, multiple banks fail simultaneously, and the collective failure impairs enough of the banking system’s capital so that large economic effects are likely to result and the government is required to intervene", S. 2. \\
\addlinespace
 KRAHNEN (2006) &
"Das systemische Bankenrisiko ergibt sich aus dem gemeinsamen Ausfall mehrerer (juristisch) unabhängiger Finanzinstitute. Das so verstandene systemische Risiko eines Finanzmarktes gibt Auskunft über die Wahrscheinlichkeit, dass aufgrund negativer Entwicklungen mehrere Bankinstitute gleichzeitig in Schwierigkeiten geraten", S. 58. \\
\addlinespace
 ACHARYA (2009) & 
"We define systemic risk as the joint failure risk arising from the correlation of returns on the asset side of bank balance sheets", S. 225. \\

\bottomrule

\end{tabularx}

\clearpage


\begin{itemize}
  \item Systemrisikobeitrag
  \begin{itemize}
    \item   LAWARE (1991):
"Systemic risk refers to the possibility that financial difficulties at one bank, or possibly a small number of banks, may spill over to many more banks and perhaps the entire financial system. So long as problems can be isolated at a limited number of banks, but confidence maintained in the broader banking and financial system, there is little or no systemic risk.", S. 550. 

\item BANK FÜR INTERN. ZAHLUNGS- AUSGLEICH (1994):
"The risk that the failure of a participant to meet its contractual obligations may in turn cause other participants to default, with the chain reaction leading to broader financial difficulties", S. 177. 

\item ROCHET/TIROLE (1996): 
"Systemic risk refers to the propagation of an agent's economic distress to other agents linked to that agent through financial transactions", S. 733.
  
\item  HELLWIG (1998):  
"[Systemrisiko soll] das Problem bezeichnen, daß (!) aufgrund von wechselseitigen Abhängigkeiten verschiedener Institutionen in einem Finanzsystem die Schwierigkeiten einer Institution die Funktionsfähigkeit des gesamten Systems infrage stellen können", S. 125. 
\end{itemize} 

\item Systemrisikoempfindlichkeit

\begin{itemize}

\item DAVIS (1995)  
",Systemic risk‘ [is] used to describe a disturbance in financial markets which entails unanticipated changes in prices and quantities in credit or asset markets, which lead to a danger of failure of financial firms, and which in turn threatens to spread so as to disrupt the payments mechanism and capacity of the financial system to allocate capital", S. 117. 

\item BARTHOLOMEW/ WHALEN (1995) 
"Systemic risk refers to an event having effects on the entire banking, financial, or economic system rather than just one or a few institutions", S. 4. 

\item MISHKIN (1995) 
"Systemic risk is the likelihood of a sudden, usually unexpected, event that disrupts information in financial markets, making them unable to effectively channel funds to those parties with the most productive investment opportunities", S. 32. 

\end{itemize}

\item Systemkorrelationsrisiko

\begin{itemize}
\item  DAS/UPPAL (2004)  
"The risk from infrequent events that are highly correlated across a large number of assets", S. 2810. 

\item ERGUNGOR/ THOMSON (2005) 
"In a systemic crisis, multiple banks fail simultaneously, and the collective failure impairs enough of the banking system’s capital so that large economic effects are likely to result and the government is required to intervene", S. 2. 

\item KRAHNEN (2006) 
"Das systemische Bankenrisiko ergibt sich aus dem gemeinsamen Ausfall mehrerer (juristisch) unabhängiger Finanzinstitute. Das so verstandene systemische Risiko eines Finanzmarktes gibt Auskunft über die Wahrscheinlichkeit, dass aufgrund negativer Entwicklungen mehrere Bankinstitute gleichzeitig in Schwierigkeiten geraten", S. 58. 

\item ACHARYA (2009)  
"We define systemic risk as the joint failure risk arising from the correlation of returns on the asset side of bank balance sheets", S. 225. 

\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: perfekt solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Does this help-- you are using tabularx package but not enabling it by using the the X type of column 00 I have modified part of the table -- you could repeat the treatment for the lower rows

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone} 

\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx} \textwidth{lLL}

\toprule

& Autor (Jahr) & Definition \\ 
\hline

\multirow{32}*{\rotatebox{90}{Systemrisikobeitrag}}
& LAWARE (1991) &
"Systemic risk refers to the possibility that financial difficulties at one bank, or 
possibly a small number of banks, may spill over to many more banks and perhaps the 
  entire financial system. So long as problems can be isolated at a limited number of 
 banks, but confidence maintained in the broader banking and financial system, there 
 is little or no systemic risk.", S. 550. \\ 
& BANK FÜR INTERN. ZAHLUNGS- AUSGLEICH (1994) &
"The risk that the failure of a participant to meet its contractual obligations may in 
 turn cause other participants to default, with the chain reaction leading to broader 
 financial difficulties", S. 177. \\
& ROCHET/TIROLE (1996) &
"Systemic risk refers to the propagation of an agent's economic distress to other 
agents linked to that agent through financial transactions", S. 733.  \\
& HELLWIG (1998) & 
"[Systemrisiko soll] das Problem bezeichnen, daß (!) aufgrund von wechselseitigen 
 Abhängigkeiten verschiedener Institutionen in einem Finanzsystem die Schwierigkeiten  
 einer Institution die Funktionsfähigkeit des gesamten Systems infrage stellen 
 können", 
 S. 125. \\
\bottomrule

\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Very small variation of nice @js bibra answer (+1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{ragged2e}   % added
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X} % changed

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx} \textwidth{ c
                    >{\hsize=0.8\hsize}L
                    >{\hsize=1.2\hsize}L @{}}
    \toprule
& Autor (Jahr) & Definition \\
    \midrule    % changed
\multirow{23}*{\rotatebox{90}{Systemrisikobeitrag}}
    & LAWARE (1991) &
"Systemic risk refers to the possibility that financial difficulties at one bank, or
possibly a small number of banks, may spill over to many more banks and perhaps the
  entire financial system. So long as problems can be isolated at a limited number of
 banks, but confidence maintained in the broader banking and financial system, there
 is little or no systemic risk.", S. 550. \\
    \addlinespace  % added
    & BANK FÜR INTERN. ZAHLUNGS- AUSGLEICH (1994) &
"The risk that the failure of a participant to meet its contractual obligations may in
 turn cause other participants to default, with the chain reaction leading to broader
 financial difficulties", S. 177. \\
    \addlinespace
    & ROCHET/TIROLE (1996) &
"Systemic risk refers to the propagation of an agent's economic distress to other
agents linked to that agent through financial transactions", S. 733.  \\
    \addlinespace
    & HELLWIG (1998) &
"[Systemrisiko soll] das Problem bezeichnen, daß (!) aufgrund von wechselseitigen
 Abhängigkeiten verschiedener Institutionen in einem Finanzsystem die Schwierigkeiten
 einer Institution die Funktionsfähigkeit des gesamten Systems infrage stellen
 können",
 S. 125. \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the above source by adjusting the `tabular` environment. Try this:

```
\documentclass{standalone} 

\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\bgroup
\def\arraystretch{1.5}%  1 is the default, change whatever you need
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular} {l>{\arraybackslash}p{4.45cm}p{5cm}}

\toprule

& Autor (Jahr) & Definition \\ 
\hline

\multirow{14}*{\rotatebox{90}{Systemrisikobeitrag}}
& LAWARE (1991) & "Systemic risk refers to the possibility that financial difficulties at one bank, or possibly a small number of banks, may spill over to many more banks and perhaps the entire financial system. So long as problems can be isolated at a limited number of banks, but confidence maintained in the broader banking and financial system, there is little or no systemic risk.", S. 550. \\ 
& BANK FÜR INTERN. ZAHLUNGS-AUSGLEICH (1994) &
"The risk that the failure of a participant to meet its contractual obligations may in turn cause other participants to default, with the chain reaction leading to broader financial difficulties", S. 177. \\
& ROCHET/TIROLE (1996) &
"Systemic risk refers to the propagation of an agent's economic distress to other agents linked to that agent through financial transactions", S. 733.  \\
& HELLWIG (1998) & 
"[Systemrisiko soll] das Problem bezeichnen, daß (!) aufgrund von wechselseitigen Abhängigkeiten verschiedener Institutionen in einem Finanzsystem die Schwierigkeiten einer Institution die Funktionsfähigkeit des gesamten Systems infrage stellen können", S. 125. \\

\noalign{\bigskip}
\cline{2-3}

\multirow{10}*{\rotatebox{90}{Systemrisikoempfindlichkeit}}
& DAVIS (1995) & 
",Systemic risk‘ [is] used to describe a disturbance in financial markets which entails unanticipated changes in prices and quantities in credit or asset markets, which lead to a danger of failure of financial firms, and which in turn threatens to spread so as to disrupt the payments mechanism and capacity of the financial system to allocate capital", S. 117. \\
& BARTHOLOMEW/WHALEN (1995) &
"Systemic risk refers to an event having effects on the entire banking, financial, or economic system rather than just one or a few institutions", S. 4. \\
& MISHKIN (1995) &
"Systemic risk is the likelihood of a sudden, usually unexpected, event that disrupts information in financial markets, making them unable to effectively channel funds to those parties with the most productive investment opportunities", S. 32. \\

\noalign{\bigskip}
\cline{2-3}

\multirow{12}*{\rotatebox{90}{Systemkorrelationsrisiko}}
& DAS/UPPAL (2004) & 
"The risk from infrequent events that are highly correlated across a large number of assets", S. 2810. \\
& ERGUNGOR/ THOMSON (2005) &
"In a systemic crisis, multiple banks fail simultaneously, and the collective failure impairs enough of the banking system’s capital so that large economic effects are likely to result and the government is required to intervene", S. 2. \\
& KRAHNEN (2006) &
"Das systemische Bankenrisiko ergibt sich aus dem gemeinsamen Ausfall mehrerer (juristisch) unabhängiger Finanzinstitute. Das so verstandene systemische Risiko eines Finanzmarktes gibt Auskunft über die Wahrscheinlichkeit, dass aufgrund negativer Entwicklungen mehrere Bankinstitute gleichzeitig in Schwierigkeiten geraten", S. 58. \\
& ACHARYA (2009) & 
"We define systemic risk as the joint failure risk arising from the correlation of returns on the asset side of bank balance sheets", S. 225. \\

\bottomrule

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

For better visualization of texts within braces, use ``brace'' not ''brace''.

The output is as follows:

[image]

EDIT: 1

You need to edit the `tabular` environment from `{l>{\arraybackslash}p{4.45cm}p{5cm}}` to `{lp{4.45cm}p{5cm}}`. Just adding the above mentioned part, after the `\begin{tabular}` environment will help and serve your purpose.

Hope this helps.

The output after incorporating EDIT: 1.

[image]

Comment: Thats quiet good! Thank you! But how can I force the secound row to be in grouped style like in my example?

Comment: Check my recent edit.